# Automatically open iPod with GTKpod instead of Caja in MATE

Tags: mate, default-programs, ipod, media, file-association

I have an iPod 2g. It automatically opens Caja. But I want to open it with GTKpod. GTKpod also doesn't open my iPod however I don't know if that is related to the problem. And yes I know that alot of places say to go into

system settings -> details -> media

But this doesn't show up in Mate.